# Qt C++ парсинг XML файлов. Что выбрать?

Tags: c++, qt, xml

В Qt с XML файлами можно работать по разному. Например с помощью DOM, SAX, QXmlStream(Reader-Writer). Меня интересуют плюсы и минусы разных подходов и их идеология. В каком случае использовать один подход, а какой в другом. Например где лучше использовать SAX, а где QXmlStream(Writer-Reader). Можно с примерами тонкостей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень просто и к Qt не имеет отношения.

## DOM

### плюсы

- один вызов и все распарсено в дерево, которое можно исследовать вдоль и в поперек
- дерево легко модифицировать, что бы потом сохранить измененный xml
- обычно идет с поддержкой XPath, что упрощает различные запросы

### минусы

- нужно много памяти. Беглая оценка  - размер xml*3.
- медленно
- невозможно парсить  неполный xml

## SAX

## плюсы

- быстрый
- потребляет мало памяти, хорошие реализации потребляют совсем мало.

## минусы

- только для чтения
- только в один проход.
- построено на событиях, иногда бывает сложно использовать.
- сложно делать выборки

## QXmlStream

## плюсы

- мне нравиться апи - просто читаешь по тегу
- должно быть быстро
- должно быть не требовательно к памяти

## минусы

- похоже, что однопроходный (надо проверить)
- сложно делать выборки